# Parsing html file using JSOUP and mapping it to key-value pairs in JAVA

Tags: java, html, parsing, hashmap, jsoup

I have parsed HTML using Jsoup and I'm trying to get key value pair out of it.

This is the HTML file, which contains key words in `dt dlterm` and values in `dd`:

```html
<div class="section" id="GUID-1BF02E47-1ECC-4CCF-A903-2A8621DB5FBA__GUID- 20A253C1-02AD-4413-9570-C0178C01E616">
  <div class="p">
    <dl class="dl">
      <dt class="dt dlterm">
    <a name="GUID-1BF02E47-1ECC-4CCF-A903-2A8621DB5FBA__GUID-942CC4F1-90F8- 4B83-9647-A3D086063B0C"><!----></a>Incident</dt>
      <dd class="dd">detials of one</dd>
      <dt class="dt dlterm"><a name="GUID-1BF02E47-1ECC-4CCF-A903- 2A8621DB5FBA__GUID-0F5CFEC5-6714-4000-A733-79DDB49B4C63"><!----> </a>Risk</dt>
      <dd class="dd">details of it two</dd>
      <dt class="dt dlterm"><a name="GUID-1BF02E47-1ECC-4CCF-A903- 2A8621DB5FBA__GUID-C731C50A-947F-431B-9CEE-1FFD1BA40EEA"><!----> </a>Event</dt>
      <dd class="dd">detials of it three.</dd>
    </dl>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is what I tried:

```
static Map<Object, Object> maps;

public static Map<Object, Object> getSet(Document doc) {
    maps = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
    String key ="";
    String value = "";
    Elements elemname1 = doc.getElementsByClass("dt dlterm");
    Elements elemname2 = doc.getElementsByClass("dd");

    List<Object> keys = new ArrayList<Object>();
    List<Object> values = new ArrayList<Object>();
    for (Element i : elemname1) {
        key = i.ownText();
        keys.add(key);
    }
    for(Element j : elemname2) {
        value = j.ownText();
        values.add(value);
    }
    System.out.println(maps);
    return maps;
}

public static void main (String args[]) throws Exception {
    String filePath ="someFilePath.html";
    File input = new File(filePath);
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "");
    getSet(doc);
}
```

The expexted result is like this:

```
{ 
    Event = detials of one,
    Incident = detials of two,
    Risk = detials of three 
}
```

What im getting is:

```
{[Incident, Risk, Event] = [detials of one,detials of two,detials of three]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use this:

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);

Elements dts = document.getElementsByClass("dt dlterm");
Elements dds = document.getElementsByClass("dd");

if (dts.size() != dds.size()) {
    // ensure same sizes of both lists
}

HashMap<String, String> values = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < dts.size(); i++) {
    values.put(dts.get(i).text(), dds.get(i).text());
}
```

Or in just one statement using Java Streams:

```
Map<String, String> values = IntStream.range(0, Math.min(dts.size(), dds.size())).boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> dts.get(i).text(),i -> dds.get(i).text()));
```

The result will be this:

```
{Risk=details of it two, Event=detials of it three., Incident=detials of one}
```

If you want to make sure the order in the map is the same as in the HTML code use a `LinkedHashMap` instead of a `HashMap`.

Answer (score 0):

You can put results into map while collecting them in one loop.
Replace both `for` loops with this one:

```
for (int i = 0; i < elemname1.size(); i++) {
    key = elemname1.get(i).ownText();
    value = elemname2.get(i).ownText();
    maps.put(key, value);
}
```

output:

```
{Risk=details of it two, Event=detials of it three., Incident=detials of one}
```